# Screen optimization in android

Tags: android, screen, android-widget

I want to do screen optimization. That means once I develop the UI in android it should fit exactly the same in all android enabled phones.

So how do i do it?

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by 'exactly the same' ?
because there are different screens, not only by resolution , but also by ratio, so some are square and some are taller.
So it cant be 'exactly the same'

Comment: ya you got exactly the same....i was talking about the different android mobile screen....so i am facing problem that is Once i develop UI in the emulator, it may or may not look or fitted in actual mobile as in looking or fitting in emulator..

so is there anyway to do screen (graphics) optimization ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want your UI to look exactly the same on all Android devices. As Daniel says, this is impossible, as Android devices differ hugely, due to different screen sizes, ratios and resolutions.

Fortunately, the Android UI system was designed **precisely** with different screens in mind. Given your UI design, it'll try it's best to make it work on the user's device, no matter what size or orientation it is. Buttons and labels and windows and images will adjust to fill the available space as specified by the UI designer.

Unless you have a specific technical reason to limit yourself to a rigid UI of specific dimensions, I'd advise you get to grips with Android's UI and components!

Comment: ok thanx for answer...found really helpful.
mine meaning was that some labels, images or any controls are appeared nice in emulator whereas whenever i am going to see it in Real Android Phone then their positions (x,y) are different than the emulator

Comment: Yep the absolute X/Y positions will be different, but use the UI components wisely (e.g. use relative positioning and proportional dimensions rather than absolute dimensions) and Android will sort the rest out. 

Then your app will look great, you'll have saved yourself lots of effort, and all your users on their different devices will love you!